# How to route domain via openvpn cloud to aws internal load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, openvpn

am trying to route console.example.com to an internal load balancer that is located in a private subnet. My current architecture is as follows:

- I have a public VPC and a private VPC.
- A React app is running on an ECS cluster and its service (console-service) is located in the private VPC.
- The internal load balancer has two listeners: one for HTTP on port 80, which forwards requests to port 443, and the other for HTTPS on port 443, which forwards requests to the task definition for the console-service. Additionally, the listener on port 443 has a certificate for console.example.com.
- The OpenVPN connector's instance is located in the public VPC.
- The public and private VPCs communicate with each other via a transit gateway.

I know that the routes are working because if I reach the console-service's private IP (private-ip:3000), I can access the website. I also know that the certificate and load balancer are working because if I SSH into an instance that is located in the private VPC and curl console.example.com, I can access the website. I believe that the issue is with the configuration of the OpenVPN's DNS settings. Currently, I added a network application that is like console.example.com - my-network, but I still cannot access the website with the domain.

Comment: If you believe the issue is with OpenVPN's DNS settings, why didn't you include any details of OpenVPN's DNS settings in your question? Please edit your question to include those details.

Comment: I said I added a network application to my network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I made a rookie mistake. I just need to add HTTP/HTTPS to the security group's inbound rules that I use for my load-balancer.